# unhandled exception in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, try-catch, unhandled-exception

the error has been caught but why these errors

```
onPressed: () {
            getName().then((value){
              print(value);
              print('The Last');
              throw('000');

            }).catchError((error){
              print('error (${error.toString()}) has been caught');
            });
        },
```

this is function

```
Future<String> getName() async
  {
    return 'Basel Elazaly';
  }
}
```

and these are output:

> Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s) (onError): The error handler of Future.catchError must return a value of the future's type

Answer (score 0):

Add a throw in catch error like this

```
onPressed: () {
            getName().then((value){
              print(value);
              print('The Last');
              throw('000');

            }).catchError((error){
              print('error (${error.toString()}) has been caught');
              throw("some other error");//<--here 
            });
        },
```

Comment: I would assume the point of a catch is *not* to just throw another error....

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
            onPressed: () {
              print(getName());
              print('The Last');
              throw('000');            
            },
```

Function

```
String getName()
  {
    return 'Basel Elazaly';
  }
```

It should work properly.

Comment: You just added *more* compiler errors.

Comment: Kindly do flutter clean and then try again.

Comment: And I have updated the code, please check that

Comment: Now you have just removed the OPs logic... yes, when you remove the code that had the error, the error is gone. That is both obvious and unhelpful. I think the Op asked how to make it work, not how to just remove it.

Comment: What is the point of using async when that is not required?

Comment: I would guess that this is just their example. Anyway, your example will just throw, it's pretty clear the OP wants to catch that, which you just removed instead of fixed.

Comment: but the code is pretty straight forward and there no chance of getting any exception in this and his code was throwing error as he was using async await in the function which doesn't contain any future function or reference

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with that. And telling me that the code is straightforward and cannot throw, when it literally has the line `throw('000');` hardcoded in it is kinda ironic.

Answer (score -1):

Just program for this century, using `async`/`await` instead of `.then()`. It will get a lot easier:

```
onPressed: () async {
       try {
         final value = await getName();
         print(value);
         print('The Last');
         throw('000');
        }
        catch(error){
          print('error (${error.toString()}) has been caught');
        }
    },
```

Official guidance: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#handling-errors